# Does jqgrid 3.6.4 support datatype:local

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I want to display some data that is stored locally in the client-side ( in the form of JS array) on the jqgrid. But when I use jqgrid 3.6.4, nothing happens, while for jqgrid 4.0.0, it works fine.

So, does jqgrid 3.6.4 support datatype:local, or is there another way to get the local data in this version of jqgrid?

My code snippet is as follows:
objArrayData is the data array.

```
jQuery("#testLookupTable").jqGrid({
                datatype: 'local',
                data: objArrayData,
                colNames:['Stmt ID','Code','Definition'],
                colModel:[
                        {name:'id',index:'id', width:0, align:'center', sortable:false, hidden:true},
                        {name:'code_Q',index:'code_Q', width:20, align:'center', sortable:false},
                        {name:'defn',index:'defn', width:20, align:'center', sortable:false}
                ],
                autowidth: true,
                hoverrows: true,
                gridview: true,
                height: '100px',
                sortname: 'id',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: "desc",
                hidegrid: false  
            });
```

**UPDATE:**

The addRowData is not working properly. It is repeating the data in the array over and over. In IE, this is leading to stackoverflow.

My new snippet:

```
 jQuery("testLookupTable").jqGrid({
                datatype: 'local',
                //data: objArrayCR7,
                colNames:['Stmt ID','Code','Definition'],
                colModel:[
                        {name:'id',index:'id', width:0, align:'center', sortable:false, hidden:true},
                        {name:'code_Q',index:'code_Q', width:20, align:'center', sortable:false},
                        {name:'defn',index:'defn', width:20, align:'center', sortable:false}
                ],
                autowidth: true,
                hoverrows: true,
                gridview: true,
                height: '100px',
                sortname: 'id',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: "desc",
                hidegrid: false,
                gridComplete: function(){
                    $('#testLookupTable').addRowData('code_Q',objArrayCR7);
                }  
            });
```

**SOLVED** (*updated*):

Found my mistake:

I should put this line:

```
  $('#testLookupTable').addRowData('code_Q',objArrayCR7);
```

outside of the .jqgrid().

Someone correct me if I am wrong, I found that every time the .addRowData() is run the grid reloads, so the gridComplete event is fired every time. This created an infinite loop in my previous code.

Comment: When you figure out your own answer,  you should post it as an answer, so it can be voted on.  You can get points for that and you can see what others think of that approach vs. Oleg's approach, etc.

Comment: OK.. will do that. Just got a message saying I have to wait for 3 more hours before I can answer my own question. Not enough reps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filling of local jqGrid with respect of `data: objArrayData` is supported starting with 3.7 version. The most performance advantage of receive if you would use `data` parameter together with `gridview: true`.

In 3.6.4 version you have to fill grid with respect of [addRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods).

I recommend you to use only the recent version of jqGrid. Currently it's version 4.1.2.

Comment: I need to use the 3.6.4 version. So, I don't have much choice.

Comment: Work stuff. Using the package that others were using.

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake:

I should put this line:

```
 $('#testLookupTable').addRowData('code_Q',objArrayCR7);
```

outside of the .jqgrid().

Someone correct me if I am wrong, I found that every time the .addRowData() is run the grid reloads, so the gridComplete event is fired every time. This created an infinite loop in my previous code.